# App:compileDebugRenderscript and Gradle Sync Issues Error

Tags: java, android, android-studio

On Android Studio 3.5 I face these errors:

> finished with non-zero exit value 1

and

> `app:compiledebugrenderscript` and execute taskaction errors.

https://ibb.co/ZzbwRL7

https://ibb.co/pwVBQnX

https://ibb.co/4VxJ4ZY

`apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    compileOptions.encoding = 'ISO-8859-1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "......"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled = true
        versionCode 7
        versionName "7"

        renderscriptTargetApi 28
        //renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true // don't use support library as it bloats the APK, and we don't need pre-4.4 support
        //need build tools higher than 20 at least to support ScriptIntrinsicHistogram

        testApplicationId "......"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
    }


    dexOptions {

        jumboMode = true
        preDexLibraries = false
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    compileOptions {

        sourceCompatibility '1.7'
        targetCompatibility '1.7'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
}



dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Provide a brief description of what are you trying to achieve and a description of the desired result.
In addition, explain what have you already tried to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

within the dependencies section try to change the version of appCompact:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```